# invalid date error on firefox browser and mobile phone

Tags: javascript, date, charts

Date working with chrome browser but invalid date error on firefox and mobile

```
var mydate = new Date(value[4]);
```

value[4] is 01-04-2019

```
console.log(mydate);
```

Below is result of console.log

```
 Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
```

I am getting invalid date error on firefox and mobile devices.How can I fix this?

Comment: It is hard to answer this without knowing what type and value `value[4]` has

Comment: value[4] is 01-04-2019

Answer (score 1):

See [documentation of the `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Your date string `01-04-2019` is not compliant with [IETF RFC 2822 / ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), so Firefox is correct to reject it as invalid date. It seems Google Chrome is simply more lenient.

A compliant version of your date would be: `2019-04-01` (YYYY-MM-DD format)